# What someone is called who supports you

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call someone who supports others by checking in with them when they're trying to achieve a goal?  Not a sponsor.

Comment: Mentor?  Coach, counsel, pilot, shepherd, tutor?

Comment: How is 'checking in with somebody' supporting them?  If you could make that clear, you might get better answers.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has mentioned the most obvious choice yet: ***supporter***.

Comment: A *phrase* used for this is **accountability partner** - [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accountability_partner).

Answer (score 3):

**advocate**, ad·vo·cate \ˈad-və-kət, -ˌkāt\ noun –[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/advocate)

> 3:  one that supports or promotes the interests of another

If my lab partner wasn't such a good *advocate*, I'd have failed physics.

Comment: Is it? Can you justify that assertion? An advocate is usually someone who speaks up for someone or something else (and supports them in that sense).

Comment: An even better example is what I've done to help this new user by showing them the ropes through editing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for "patron"?

> - One that supports, protects, or champions someone or something, such as an institution, event, or cause; a benefactor: a patron of the arts. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/patron)

e.g.

- "Lorenzo De Medici is said to have been a patron of the arts."
- "John has found a patron in Dr. Cole."

Answer (score 0):

I think "coach" may fit here. Coaching has by nature a 'caring' and personal quality to it. The coach or person checking-in must be somehow invested in the other persons success. Their success is the coach's success. Being willing to be supportive in this way (with regular check-ins) requires somewhat of a parental outlook. They agree to be caring enough to be a (however) constant in that persons life. This requires commitment from both the coach and the coached, thus the inevitable personal aspect of the relationship.

The way I find "just the right word" to use is, I start with whatever word I first think of, even if I know it's the wrong one (like 'sponsor'). I use either Thesaurus or dictionary to find its synonyms. And I just go from there, checking out the words and definitions and as I get closer, the context in which they are used until I'm satisfied I have the right word to express my thought.  Good luck